# Finding local minima assignments of nearest neighbors for minimum weight matching

Tags: algorithm, matching

I have a pairwise distance matrix for 2n points and ultimately I want to find a minimum weight total matching that splits the points into n disjoint connected pairs. Often the optimal matching will be pretty "obvious", where all points are connected to their 1st or 2nd nearest neighbor. So I was wondering, if I have the nearest neighbors for each point in sorted order, how can I enumerate "minimal" nearest neighbor matchings meaning that there is no way to reassign the matching so that each point is connected to the same neighbor or a closer neighbor, and at least one point is connected to a closer neighbor? The set of all such minimal nearest neighbor pairings would then be the set of candidates for minimum weight total matching. If the points come in n pairs where the points in each pair are each other's 1st nearest neighbor then the solution is trivial. I'm hoping to get similar speed-up when there are matchings where each point is connected to its 1st or 2nd nearest neighbor.

Comment: Bipartite matching or general?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat General matching, given 2n nodes find n disjoint pairs of 2 distinct nodes each.

Comment: Is using something like Blossom V not an option?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Sure Blossom algorithm is an option for a polynomial time solution. But when there is a matching that matches every node to its 1st or 2nd nearest neighbor it seems like we can do better. That's what I'm asking about...if every point can be matched with a very closeby neighbor, can we enumerate the minimal near neighbor assignments and get a small number of assignments that can be checked quickly to find the minimal weight matching?

Comment: I meant the particular implementation by Vladimir Kolmogorov, which maintains the dual solution in a sophisticated manner that strikes me as possibly subsuming your idea about minimal matchings.